# Why does the Keras Early Stopping function not stop the training, although the monitored value is increasing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am trying to train a neural Network for a regression problem and I implemented the Keras Early Stopping Function to avoid overfitting.

Now the early stopping function stops the programm almost directly when I montior "val_loss" and the result is a useless NN, but when I monitor "val_mse" the training goes on and on without stopping, although i can see "val_mse" increasing throught the training and i set patience = 0.

I seem to have misunderstood the Early Stopping Callback since i thought that it does monitor the value and stop the training as soon as the value starts increasing again.

```
np.random.seed(7)

#Define Input
tf_features_64 = np.load("IN_2.npy")
tf_labels_64 = np.load("OUT_2.npy")
tf_features_32 = tf_features_64.astype(np.float32)
tf_labels_32 = tf_labels_64.astype(np.float32)

X = tf_features_32
Y = tf_labels_32[0:10680, 4:8]
#Define Callback
tbCallBack = TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph{}', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True) #TensorBoard Monitoring
esCallback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mse',
                           min_delta=0,
                           patience=0,
                           verbose=1,
                           mode='min')

#create Layers
visible = Input(shape=(33,))
x = Dropout(.1)(visible)
#x = Dense(63)(x)
#x = Dropout(.4)(x)
output = Dense(4)(x)  

Optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001
                            #amsgrad = True)

model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs = output)
model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
              loss=['mse'],
              metrics=['mae', 'mse']
              )
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=8000, batch_size=20, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.35, callbacks=[tbCallBack, esCallback])
```

As an example, i get the following output where i can clearly see, that the val_mse increases over the epochs.

```
  20/6942 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0373 - mean_squared_error: 0.0022
1620/6942 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0011 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0251 - mean_squared_error: 0.0011
3260/6942 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0015 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0290 - mean_squared_error: 0.0015
4900/6942 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0017 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0301 - mean_squared_error: 0.0017
6500/6942 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0016 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0301 - mean_squared_error: 0.0016
6942/6942 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step - loss: 0.0016 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0294 - mean_squared_error: 0.0016 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0240 - **val_mean_squared_error: 0.0011**
**Epoch 334/8000**

  20/6942 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0025 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0367 - mean_squared_error: 0.0025
1620/6942 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0012 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0257 - mean_squared_error: 0.0012
3260/6942 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0014 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0274 - mean_squared_error: 0.0014
4860/6942 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0014 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0268 - mean_squared_error: 0.0014
6400/6942 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0012 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0254 - mean_squared_error: 0.0012
6942/6942 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0012 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0249 - mean_squared_error: 0.0012 - val_loss: 0.0032 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0393 - **val_mean_squared_error: 0.0032**
**Epoch 335/8000**

  20/6942 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.5175e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0243 - mean_squared_error: 9.5175e-04
1620/6942 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0017 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0312 - mean_squared_error: 0.0017        
3260/6942 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0013 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0271 - mean_squared_error: 0.0013
4860/6942 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0014 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0277 - mean_squared_error: 0.0014
6460/6942 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0013 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0266 - mean_squared_error: 0.0013
6942/6942 [==============================] - 0s 38us/step - loss: 0.0013 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0268 - mean_squared_error: 0.0013 - val_loss: 0.0046 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0491 - **val_mean_squared_error: 0.0046**
**Epoch 336/8000**
```

Comment: I don't think `val_mse` has any in-built meaning in Keras unless Keras has changed significantly in the past six months. Just because `mse` is a recognized keyword, it does not mean that `val_mse` is also recognized. Why not use `val_loss` itself? If your loss is `mse`, that means `val_loss = mse + regularization penalty`. You should use `val_loss`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no metric called `val_mse` in your code, your callback is monitoring the wrong metric. There is `val_mean_squared_error` but that's not the same as `val_mse`.

You should change the metric to be monitored from `val_mse` to `val_mean_squared_error` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

val_mse works in python version 3.7 and val_mean_squared_error works in version 3.6